# How to make a vertical range widget for displaying availability throughout the day in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, widget

I am working on a widget that will display the availability of an item throughout the week. I really like the way that Google Calendar and the Apple Calendars apps display an event that spans over the hours of the day and mocked up [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkWV3.jpg) widget to get my idea across.

So far in Flutter I have the days of the week as well as the hours time range on the left side. However, I've been struggling designing a way to display the bars overtop of the hours of the day as well as the current time marker that would span overtop of the bars. Obviously there are the vertical range slider plugins, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you looked into bar chart libraries? I'd guess your data can be displayed in that fashion.

Comment: I did look into this and it's definitely a possibility, but I would hate to install a whole package to only use it in one place in my app.

Comment: You could always look at the package code - should give you a good starting point and/or code to pull from.